# The eigenvalues of $A+I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I recently read the following claim:

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. If $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A + I$ then $(\mu - 1)$ is an eigenvalue of $A $.

I do not see why this should be true. Is this true at all?

Comment: What is the definition of $\mu$ being an eigenvalue of $(A+I)$? It basically follows from the definition (also there is a typo: $A+I$ in the end should be $A$)

Comment: There is a vector $v$ such that $(A+I)v = \mu v$.

Comment: Yes. So what does this tell you about $Av$?

Comment: Ah because $(A+I)v = Av + v = \mu x$ and we can substract $x$ from both sides. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an obvious typo in the question. At the end you have typed $A+I$ instead of $A$.

There exists a  non-zero vector $x$ such that $(Ax+I)=\mu x$. Hence $Ax=(\mu- 1)x$, so the answer is YES.